# Cannot Access IP and PORT on kubernetes minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have created web deployment and service on kubernetes
When i list the service with `$ kubectl get service` command to list IP and Port to access the webpage but when i try to access it the site cant be reached.
It seem if kubernetes on minikube didnt pull image from docker hub..

Here my example script..
I use Kubernetes v1.19.2 with default driver Docker 19.03.8

1. `$ kubectl create -f web-pets.yaml`

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: web
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: pets
>       service: web
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: pets
>         service: web
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - image: nginx:alpine-1.19.2
>         name: web
>         ports:
>         - containerPort: 80
>           protocol: TCP
> ---
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: web
> spec:
>   type: NodePort
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
>     protocol: TCP
>   selector:
>     app: pets
>     service: web
> ```

2. Output create `web-pets.yaml`

> ```
> $ kubectl create -f web-pets.yaml
> deployment.apps/web created
> service/web created
> ```

3. Output `$ kubectl get service`

> ```
> $ kubectl get service
> NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
> kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        11h
> web          NodePort    10.110.107.234   <none>        80:30100/TCP   41s
> ```

4. Output `$ kubectl get service web`

> ```
> Name:                     web
> Namespace:                default
> Labels:                   <none>
> Annotations:              <none>
> Selector:                 app=pets,service=web
> Type:                     NodePort
> IP:                       10.109.10.68
> Port:                     <unset>  3000/TCP
> TargetPort:               3000/TCP
> NodePort:                 <unset>  31830/TCP
> Endpoints:                <none>
> Session Affinity:         None
> External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
> Events:                   <none>
> ```

5. When list all docker images no nginx image

> ```
> $ docker images
> REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
> kicbase/stable                 v0.0.12-snapshot3   25ac91b9c8d7  4 weeks ago   952MB
> gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase    v0.0.12-snapshot3   25ac91b9c8d7  4 weeks ago   952MB
> ```

6. Deploy web description

> ```
> $ kubectl describe deploy web
> Name:                   web
> Namespace:              default
> CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 24 Sep 2020 17:25:42 +0700
> Labels:                 <none>
> Annotations:            <none>
> Selector:               app=pets,service=web
> Replicas:               1 desired | 0 updated | 0 total | 0 available | 0 unavailable
> StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
> MinReadySeconds:        0
> RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
> Pod Template:
>   Labels:  app=pets
>            service=web
>   Containers:
>    web:
>     Image:        nginx:alpine-1.19.2
>     Port:         3000/TCP
>     Host Port:    0/TCP
>     Environment:  <none>
>     Mounts:       <none>
>   Volumes:        <none>
> OldReplicaSets:   <none>
> NewReplicaSet:    <none>
> Events:           <none>
> ```

7. `$ kubectl get pods`

> ```
> $ kubectl get pods
> No resources found in default namespace.
> ```

8. `$ kubectl get events`

> ```
> LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON                    OBJECT          MESSAGE
> 7m13s       Normal   Starting                  node/minikube   Starting kubelet.
> 7m11s       Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/minikube   Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
> 7m11s       Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/minikube   Node minikube status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
> 7m11s       Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID      node/minikube   Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
> 7m12s       Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced   node/minikube   Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
> 6m28s       Normal   Starting                  node/minikube   Starting kube-proxy.
> ```

Comment: Add output of `kubectl describe svc web`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu added the output

Comment: Pods are running?

Comment: No.. i am not create any pod
How to do it ?

Comment: Add output of `kubectl describe deploy web` and `kubectl get pods`

Comment: Added the deploy web describe output

Comment: Add output of `kubectl get events`

Comment: Added all the output

Answer (score 3):

Nginx listens on port `80`. Hence you need to use port `80` instead of port `3000` in the deployment and service. From the [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) you should be able to access it using
`minikube service web`

Comment: But it will work if the image not pulled from docker hub?
I ran `$ docker images` no nginx:1.19.2-alpine image

Still cant access it i have changed to port 80

Comment: No it will not..Can you try `docker pull` in the minikube to see if any error is happening

Comment: I reinstall the minikube and the image can pulled automatically and now i can access it with `$ minikube service web`
thank u for ur all help ^^